# Alternate for httpredirect

Tags: asp.net, http-redirect

We have two different .NET application and now we have fit in Application 'B' inside the application 'A'.

Whosoever tries to access Application B directly, needs to be redirected to 'A'. I see we do have an `httpredirect` option but in our IIS 7 servers, it's not installed. Could anyone please let me know if there is any other alternative.

Comment: Installing redirect is not an option?  You should be able to add it in the server features...

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a Http Module for Application B that redirects requests to Application A.

[Redirect URL Using HttpModule Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633241/redirect-url-using-httpmodule-asp-net)

[Introduction to HTTP Modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms178468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: In the first link, there is a comment for the answer saying, we have to add to web.config. Could you please let me know what we need to add?

Comment: That depends on where you deployed the new HttpModule. For example, if you created it within the code base of Application B, you would then go into the web.config of Application B and add an entry under the httpModules section.